# 32pixel 2d sprites in Unity look wonkey when in game mode but fine in scene mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

It's my first time making a game with unity. When I import my sprites they are blurry so I changed the filter mode to point, and the image appears fine until I play the game which is where my problem is.When I play the game, the pixels blend together and butcher the image.
Any help would be much appreciated , thanks.
[here are my camera settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p0Kr.png)

After downloading pixel perfect:

[game mode after pixel perfect(looks how it should)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EcQy.png)

[Here's how it looks while playing the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAPnx.png)

Comment: Can you include your camera settings? Also, did you try the Unity Pixel Perfect Camera that is available through the package manager?

Comment: I haven't used pixel perfect, but I just included a screenshot of my camera settings below the first two links.                                                                                            -thanks

Comment: your character looks like that in the game view because it has a different orthographic size then your scene camera, the best thing for you to do will be to get the pixel perfect camera from the package manager, and attach it to your camera.

Comment: thanks guys, Ive downloaded a free version of pixel perfect and it has made a difference for sure. It's still blending the colors together though, any thoughts?